# issue in tranferring data from host machine to guest machine

Tags: centos

We are having one Dell PowerConnect Switch which is operated on 10 Gbps; in which six to seven Server machines are connected . In each server machine we have inserted externally one 10 Gbps Lan card .In one of these server machine we have installed Centos-6.4 (64bit) as base OS also using oracle virtual box-4.2.16 (64bit) we have installed one Centos-6.2(64bit) virtual machine (with virtual box guest addition).
My issue is If i transfer one file having size of only 60-62 MB from other server machine to the server machine in which VM we installed;data transferred very fastly within 2-3 seconds with avg speed 50-52MBps but i transfer the same amount of data from other server machine to the same above mentioned Virtual machine we saw data transfer with speed of avg 6-12 KBps.

If i perform the reverse process i.e. transfer data of same size 60-62 MB from this Virtual Machine to other physical server machine data get tranfered very fastly.

Please suggest if any one know about this issue

Comment: Have you done any troubleshooting or checked to see if others may be having a similar issue?

Comment: Yes i have done all things i.e. Bridged adaptor mode ;speed;Full duplex;Guest addition;extensions. changing some ethenet card setting of virtual machine as well but still facing an issue

Comment: today i did one more thing i took separate  laptop which is operated in 100Mbps. I disconnected one server (in which Vrtual machine installed) from switch; then connect back-to-back network cable from this server machine to laptop machine (keeping server machine virtual machine and laptop machine in same network) then i found the same above mentioned issue i.e. data transfer of size 60-62 MB from laptop to server is occured at 5MBps but data (of same size) transfer from laptop machine to virtual machine occured at avg 4-5 KBps.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when virtual machines NIC is attached to the physical NIC, not the bridge interface. Create bridge for the NIC and attach VM to that bridge.

Do not confuse it with **bridged adapter mode** - I am talking about the bridge on the host, not the guest setting.

Comment: thanks GioMac for your reply;                                                                  If i am not wrong; you mean to create Bridged Network Configuration in Host machine then add lan card of host server machine to that bridge

Comment: yes, exactly...

Comment: Thank you so much GioMac; issue has been resolved by creating briged network in Host machine;It really worked.